# Vert.x 4 eventbus serialize multiple classes with same codec

Tags: java, kotlin, vert.x, jackson-databind

Is there a way to register a codec for multiple classes? Basically, all my classes should just be serialized using a Jackson object mapper. But it seems like I have to create a custom codec for each class (even though I can abstract it a little bit using generics).

A small code example:

Codec:

```kotlin
class JacksonCodec<T>(private val mapper: ObjectMapper, private val clazz: Class<T>) : MessageCodec<T, T> {
    override fun encodeToWire(buffer: Buffer, s: T) {
        buffer.appendBytes(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(s))
    }

    override fun decodeFromWire(pos: Int, buffer: Buffer): T {
        val length = buffer.getInt(pos)
        val bytes = buffer.getBytes(pos + 4, pos + 4 + length)
        return mapper.readValue(bytes, clazz)
    }
    ...
}
```

register codec for each class I want to serialize:

```kotlin
vertx.eventBus()
        .registerDefaultCodec(A::class.java, JacksonCodec(DatabindCodec.mapper(), A::class.java))
    vertx.eventBus()
vertx.eventBus()
        .registerDefaultCodec(B::class.java, JacksonCodec(DatabindCodec.mapper(), B::class.java))
    vertx.eventBus()
```

The code examples are kotlin but same applies for Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell looking at the code, there is no way, as the class needs to be the exact match:

https://github.com/eclipse-vertx/vert.x/blob/master/src/main/java/io/vertx/core/eventbus/impl/CodecManager.java#L99

Comment: thanks for the answer. And thanks for providing the code. Looks like this is unfortunately not possible right now... I will open a request ticket for this!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, with some limitations and quirks. I would not recommend doing it.

Let's start with the limitations:

1. It can not be used in clustered mode
2. You have to declare the codec name every time you send something over the eventbus.

If you create a generic codec that encodes classes with Jackson and every time you send something over the eventbus you make sure to add it using `codecName` in the `deliveryOptions`, you can register it only once and use it for all of your classes.

Full example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val vertx = Vertx.vertx()
  vertx.eventBus().registerCodec(GenericCodec())

  vertx.eventBus().consumer<Foo>("test-address") {
    println(it.body())
    it.reply(Bar(), genericDeliveryOptions)
  }

  vertx.eventBus().request<String>("test-address", Foo(), genericDeliveryOptions) {
    println(it.result().body())
  }

  vertx.close()
}

data class Foo(
  val foo: String = "foo",
)

data class Bar(
  val bar: String = "bar",
)

class GenericCodec : MessageCodec<Any, Any> {
  companion object {
    const val NAME = "generic"
  }

  private val mapper: ObjectMapper = ObjectMapper()

  override fun encodeToWire(buffer: Buffer, s: Any) {
    buffer.appendBytes(mapper.writeValueAsBytes(s))
  }

  override fun decodeFromWire(pos: Int, buffer: Buffer): Any {
    throw RuntimeException("should never get here, unless using clustered mode")
  }

  override fun transform(s: Any): Any {
    return s
  }

  override fun name(): String {
    return NAME
  }

  override fun systemCodecID(): Byte {
    return -1
  }
}

val genericDeliveryOptions = deliveryOptionsOf(codecName = GenericCodec.NAME)
```